# upload multiple files using multerS3 and NodeJs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, multer

I've been trying for days but can't seem to figure out where I'm going wrong. My code works for a single file upload in a local folder but can't seem to upload multiple files even if I use `upload.array()` and `req.files` in multer and controller function respectively. Whereas when I try to upload a single/multiple files in my s3 bucket nothing gets uploaded at all. Below I'll also provide my model structure in case you need to see it.

**::UPDATE::**
The files are getting uploaded in s3 bucket but the database can't catch the file path. `imagePath` is coming blank inside database

route.js:

```js
const ProductController = require('./../controllers/productController');
const appConfig = require("./../config/appConfig");
const multer = require('multer');
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const multerS3 = require('multer-s3');
const path = require('path');
const s3 = new aws.S3({ accessKeyId: "***", secretAccessKey: "***" });
 var upload = multer({
    storage: multerS3({
      s3: s3,
      bucket: 'mean-ecom',
      metadata: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, {fieldName: file.originalname + path.extname(file.fieldname)});
      },
      key: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, Date.now().toString())}})});
let setRouter = (app) => {
    let baseUrl = appConfig.apiVersion;
app.post(baseUrl+'/post-product', upload.single('imagePath'), ProductController.postProduct)}
   module.exports = {
     setRouter: setRouter}
```

ProductController.postProduct:

```
const ProductModel = mongoose.model('Product')

let postProduct = (req, res) => {
    let newProduct = new ProductModel({

                imagePath: req.file && req.file.path})
            newProduct.save((err, result) => {
                if (err) { console.log('Error at saving new Product :: ProductController', err);
                 res.send(err);
            } else { 
                console.log('Successfully saved new Product'); res.send(result) }
            })}
```

productModel.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
let productSchema = new Schema(
    {
       imagePath: {
                type: String,
                default: ''    }})
mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);
```

Comment: The imagePath in the model only accept one file, it should be an array. However, for uploading many files you should use `upload.any()` and then you access their location using `req.files[index].location`

Comment: what do you by by the ```[index]``` in ```req.files[index].location``` ??? also do you mean instead of using ```upload.array('imagePath' 3)``` I need to use ```upload.any()``` ?? Please elaborate

Comment: For example, if you want to upload 3 files, you use `upload.any('imagePath')`, and then the locations would be `req.files[0].location`; `req.files[1].location` and `req.files[2].location` since `req.files` will be an array of files. The `.location` is basically the path of each file.

Comment: but the ```req.files[index].location``` is giving an error saying index is not defined

Comment: you should replace index with an actual number starting from 0 (remember is an array). So you can loop throw the files and get each location. Ex: `for (let i = 0; i < req.files.length; i++) {let imagePath = req.files[i].location;}`.

Comment: I get you. One last help will be appreciated if you can show me where to run this loop in my controller function and set the value of index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you need to do is change the model's imagePath property from a string to an array of strings, so you can store multiple images

```
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
let productSchema = new Schema(
    {
       imagePath: {type: Array}
    })
mongoose.model('Product', productSchema)
```

Then, in the router, you should use `upload.any()` (`upload.array()` should work the same way).
Finaly, if you want to store the files locations in the model array, you loop throw the files updating the model.

```
let postProduct = (req, res) => {
    // We create a temporal array with the files locations
    let files = [];
    
    // We loop throw the req.files array and store their locations in the temporal files array
    for (let i = 0; i < req.files.length; i++) {
      let file = req.files[i].location
      files.push(file)
    }

    let newProduct = new ProductModel({
            imagePath: files}) //We create the model with the temp array

    newProduct.save((err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log('Error at saving new Product :: ProductController', err);
        res.send(err);
      }
      else{
        console.log('Successfully saved new Product');
        res.send(result)
      }
    })
```